# Noah's (upgraded) ark

Tags: code-golf, permutations

As preparation for the nth Exodus, Noah decides to write a program that will decide If he will let animals on his ark.  However, Noah wants to go back to grass roots. Thus he decides that the program should be as small and as simple as possible.

**GOAL:**
Recreate the [Contrabulous Choosematron](https://theinfosphere.org/Contrabulous_Choosematron), in a way that follows evangelical stories.

**INPUT:**

The program is simple, and elegant, and takes in 2 inputs:
The species of animal [String]
and The animal's gender [boolean]

**OUTPUT:**

The program then puts out Either 'Y' or 'N', Which determines whether or not the given  animal is allowed onto the ark.

**RULES:**

Only one Animal of each species and gender is allowed on the ark. No more.
Your output can be any set of boolean values (true false, yes no, y n, yin yang) so long as they're easily distinguishable.
If your program should want to accept a list of input, rather than use STDIN, that's fine. However, each output has to be in corresponding order of the input (FIFO), as well as be in the exact same format as the input.
**This is a golf, so the lowest byte count wins, good luck**!!!!

**EXAMPLE:**

> "Monkey" true<
> y
> "Monkey" false<
> y
> "Monkey" false<
> n
> "Monkey with symbols" false<
> y
> "monkey" true<
> n

This is valid, as your program doesn't need to distinguish that `Monkey`, and `monkey with symbols` are the same thing species, however, `Monkey` and `monkey` are very much the same thing, and so the last critter would be denied.

Comment: Could you add an example to your question for completeness?

Comment: Will the species of animal only contain letters i.e. [a-zA-Z]?

Comment: @gowrath added! thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @Riley some animals names may contain hyphens. Those animals are usually on the track to getting a divorce. However, I should note, all real species of animals are valid input, excluding the shortening period added to truncate their name. Some of those will include hyphens, and spaces.

Comment: The goal and the rules contradict each other. In order to achieve the goal, the rules would have to allow seven pairs of sacrificial animals such as sheep.

Comment: @PeterTaylor the old testament is not canonical anyway.....  haha.

Comment: Do you mean "monkey with *cymbals*"?

Comment: @Jordan, no, he has a foam ochothorpe and ampersand that he carries around, and he won't give them up....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Perl, <s>15</s> 13 bytes

Includes +1 for `-n`

Input on STDIN (or 1 or more filenames as argument like `cat`), one animal and gender per line in any consistent notation. Prints a line with 1 for true, an empty line for false

```
perl -M5.010 -n ark.pl
```

`ark.pl`

```
say!${+lc}++
```

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2, 72 bytes

Takes input as a list of strings of the form "animalname T". The idea is it just uses each string as an identifier and should only print true if the string has not occurred in the list so far.

```
def f(l):k=map(str.lower,l);print[j not in k[:i]for i,j in enumerate(k)]
```

Try it [here](http://ideone.com/kqhy5A)!

Comment: Very nice, and elegant entry.

Answer (score 1):

## Python, <s>54 52</s> 50 bytes

```
def f(s,l={}):x=s.lower();r=x in l;l[x]=1;return r
```

Test case is at [**ideone**](http://ideone.com/Tm8w9K)

This borrows [this neat idea](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/92588/53748) from @gowrath, but extends it by using the fact that when a function is defined with a default argument that is mutable, like a dictionary, it acts as a memoisation (the object retains state between function calls).

Saved 2 bytes by returning None for truthy ("Y") and 0 for falsey ("N").
Save 2 more by (confusingly) returning False for truthy ("Y") and True for falsey ("N").

Answer (score 0):

## Java, <s>246</s> 218 bytes

Lowered byte count thanks to Kevin!.

Takes STDIN as input, outputs weather or not the animal is allowed to board.

```
import java.util.*;class B{public static void main(String[]a){List l=new ArrayList();Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);for(;;){String b=s.nextLine().toLowerCase();l.add(b);System.out.println(l.contains(b)?"n"‌​:"y");}}}
```

Comment: You can golf it quite a bit by removing unnecessary spaces. Also, you can remove `public` before `class`, change `args` to `a`, etc. Also, you should include the `import`s you use. Here is your code golfed: `import java.util.*;class B{public static void main(String[]a){List l=new ArrayList();Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);for(;;){String b=s.nextLine();if(l.contains(b))b="n";else{l.add(b);b="y";}System.out.println(b);}}}` (**217 bytes**) You might like to read through [Tips for golfing in Java](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/6671/tips-for-golfing-in-java). :)

Comment: Since you use `contains` to check if it's in the list or not, it doesn't matter if it's added a second, third, etc. time. So you can just always add it and use a ternary check to directly print it. So it becomes this: `import java.util.*;class B{public static void main(String[]a){List l=new ArrayList();Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);for(;;){String b=s.nextLine();l.add(b);System.out.println(l.contains(b)?"n":"y");}}}` (**202 bytes**)

Comment: Hmm btw, you neglected one of your own rules atm (_"however, `Monkey` and `monkey` are very much the same thing, and so the last critter would be denied."_) - you forgot to use `.toLowercase()` somewhere.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen is `import *;` or `import *.*;` a valid statement in java golfing? it used to work in java 6....

Answer (score 0):

### Groovy 43 Bytes

```
{s->y=[];s.collect{!y.contains(it)&&y.add(it)}}
```

Try it here: https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/edit/5147446497771520

It uses a list of tuples as the input:

```
z = [new Tuple('Monkey',true), new Tuple('Monkey',false), new Tuple('Monkey',true), new Tuple('Bee',true)]
```

Which results in:

```
[true, true, false, true]
```

The add function in groovy always returns true, and in groovy tuples have inherent comparison ability for primitive objects, so the contains actually works well for strings and integers without changing it.

So, basically just check if the list contains it and add it to the list.

- If the list already contains it we get (false && N/A)
- If it does not we get (True && True) and it is added to the running list.

This is all you really need to accomplish this, if you want to tell me to turn it into a closure or something as well it would probably cap out at approximately 45-50 bytes in Groovy.

Comment: It's a code snippet, which is not allowed. You must post a full program or a function.

Answer (score 0):

## Perl (35 + 1 for -p) 36

Takes input from STDIN, one animal per line in the form `animal T`. Where `T` is anything you want to be used for the gender (e.g. `T`/`F`, `M`/`F`). You could even have multi-character genders, or more than 2 genders (e.g. `male`/`female`/`apache helicopter`).

Includes all character on the line, so if you're inputting from a file you need a newline after the last animal.

```
$\=($a{lc()}?N:Y);$a{lc()}=1;$_='';
```

Answer (score 0):

### PowerShell v3+, 33 bytes

```
$a=@();$args|%{$_-notin$a;$a+=$_}
```

Takes input as command-line arguments of strings of the form `Animal Gender` where `Gender` is (pretty much) any identifier you want. Sets an empty array `$a`, then loops through the input arguments. Places the Boolean result of the `-notin` operator on the pipeline, and adds the current element into the `$a` array. PowerShell by default is case-insensitive when comparing strings, so `Monkey f`, `monkey f`, `mOnKeY F` and other variations will all evaluate as the same.

The resulting Booleans are left on the pipeline, and output via implicit `Write-Output` happens at program completion.

#### Example

```
PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> .\noahs-upgraded-ark.ps1 'Monkey m' 'Monkey f' 'Monkey f' 'Monkey with symbols m' 'monkey m'
True
True
False
True
False
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Dyalog APL](http://goo.gl/9KrKoM), 16 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)

Case sensitive solution:

```apl
(⍳⍴)∊(∪⍳⍨)
```

`(⍳⍴)` which indices

`∊` are member of

`⍳⍨` each entry's first occurrence in the list

Unfortunately, case-insensitivity is bulky:

```apl
(⍳⍴)∊(∪c⍳c←819⌶)
```

`c←819⌶` assign the lowercase function to *c*

`c⍳c` is the same as `⍳⍨c`. See explanation above.

[TryAPL online!](http://tryapl.org/?a=f%u2190%28%u2373%u2374%29%u220A%28%u222A%u2373%u2368%29%20%u22C4%20f%20%28%27mon%27%20%27M%27%29%28%27mon%27%20%27F%27%29%28%27mon%27%20%27F%27%29%28%27mons%27%20%27M%27%29%28%27mon%27%20%27M%27%29&run) (casing is not supported on TryAPL)

Comment: Could you `or` each character with space (32) to get a mock lowercase mapping ? That seems OK with the restricted set of special characters that ineeds to be supported

Comment: @TonHospel `or`?

Comment: `Bitwise or` of the ASCII codes. `A` is 0x41, `or` with space (0x20) and get `a` (0x61). Some languages allow an `or` directly on the characters themselves. I have no idea if APL easily supports this

Comment: @TonHospel No, APL only adjusts number of bits used to represent numbers (1,8,16,32,64,128) or characters (8,16,32), but you have to be explicit to convert characters to numbers or vice-versa.

Comment: 14 bytes: `⍳∘⍴∊∘∪(⍳⍨819⌶)`

Answer (score 0):

## Swift 2.2 169 bytes

I did not accept input from standard in I just passed an array of dictionaries to function x.

#### Golfed

```
var a=[String]();let x={(d:[[String:Bool]]) in for r in d{for(s,t)in r{let y=s.lowercaseString+t.description;a.append(y);print(a.indexOf(y)==(a.count-1) ? true:false)}}}
```

#### UnGolfed

```
var a=[String]();
let x={(d:[[String:Bool]]) in
    for r in d{
        for(s,t)in r{
            let y=s.lowercaseString+t.description;
            a.append(y);
            print(a.indexOf(y)==(a.count-1) ? true:false)
        }
    }
}
```

#### Input

```
x([["Monkey":true],["Monkey":false],["monkey":true],["Zebra":true]])
```

---

Also just for giggles did a crappy javascript version since I did not see anyone else do a javascript one.

### JS (ES6) 125 bytes

#### Golfed

```
a=[],i=0,j=0;y=(r)=>{for(;j<r.length;j+=2){var y=r[j].toLowerCase()+r[j+1];a[i]=y;console.log(a.indexOf(y)==i++?true:false)}}a=[],i=0,j=0;y=(r)=>{for(;j<r.length;j+=2){var y=r[j].toLowerCase()+r[j+1];a[i]=y;console.log(a.indexOf(y)==i++?true:false)}}
```

#### UnGolfed

```
a=[],i=0,j=0;
y=(r)=>{
  for(;j<r.length;j+=2){
    var y=r[j].toLowerCase()+r[j+1];
    a[i]=y;
    console.log(a.indexOf(y)==i++?true:false)
  }
}
```

#### Input

```
y(["Monkey", true, "Monkey", false, "monkey",true,"zebra",false])
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes

```
ŒuŒQ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opNKjkwL/H24/Ounhzhn//0dHq/vm52WnVqrrKBjG6iggcQ1wcxXKM0syFIorc5Pyc4rhcrkIg2IB)

Each animal in the list (argument) is `[species, gender]`, where `gender` can either be `1` for male or `0` for female. Output is a list of `0`s and `1`s, where `0` means "not allowed" and `1` means "allowed". This is a function, and therefore a footer has been added to show the actual result.

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>50</s> 48 bytes

```ruby
->a,*s{a.map{|x|x[0].upcase!
(s<<x).count(x)<2}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY5LCsMgFAD3nuJ1laRYKV2b3qAnEBcmKA2NH/KUKknObqG7dNXtMAyzpKFU09fLXdEzropZFdYtb1lcJUthVKhPpEXOc8dGn1xsc8dv@14nF1KEHgQBEM3Du5cuDYW4JC3pkRk14x8Q3lN8AhY7@Bl/DHvoE0lIACO@D7LWDw)

A lambda accepting an array of `[animal, gender]` pairs and returning a boolean array.

-2 bytes: Initialize the list of seen animals as a splat arg

```ruby
->a,*s{                # s is the list of animals seen so far, initially []
  a.map{ |x|           # x is the current animal
    x[0].upcase!       # Transform x's name in place to uppercase
    (d<<x).count(x)<2  # Add x to s, and return true if s has only 1 instance of x
  }
}
```